# Handling MYSQL Query Results returned from PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Using AJAX We can get php echoed data by

```
success: function(data)
```

Also We can point them to display inside any ware in the page using id of the element.
Eg-

```
$("#id").html(data);
```

My problem is how can I display those data in different places? My result gives me like 8 values and I want them to display in different places of my web page. Better if i can use php codes where ever i want to display them. eg:- `<?php echo ($row[0]); ?>`

I'am sure it is possible with PHP Sessions. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Return JSON instead of HTML, then you can extract parts of it easily and display them how and where you want.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. any references?

Comment: This [php function](http://nl1.php.net/json_encode) and this [jquery function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) would give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable and assign returned json to that variable then you can use that value anywhere in the page.

```
Var datarow;
$.ajax({
       ...,              
       success: function(dataJson) {
           datarow=dataJson
       } 
});  

$("#yourHtmlId").html(''+datarow.firstValue);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'am still working on it. To feed this dataJson variable with data in php, 
$dataJson = json_encode($row); is correct?

Comment: It Dosen't work :(

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $dataJson = json_encode($row);
  echo $dataJson;

Comment: did you check that you are getting the data in $row after using $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);?

Comment: Yes. I can display data raw in the desired location all together as well. but i cant seperate them. AJAX only point them to she specified id location provided by $("#id").html(data);

Comment: use like this:

success: function(data) {
   datarow=data
}

now in js file you can use 'datarow' how ever you wanted like
$("#id").html(datarow.firstValue);